# Function dependence on iteration variable of another function

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider two versions of implementing the same functionality.

**Version 1 -**
Functions `calculateA(),calculateB() and calculateC()` dependent on iteration variable of `calculateAll()`.

```
class Box
{
    void calculateAll()
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < _values.size(); i++)
        {
            calculateA(i);
            calculateB(i);
            calculateC(i);
        }

    }

    A calculateA(unsigned i) const
    {
        //Calcualate A based on _values 
    }

    B calculateB(unsigned i) const
    {
        //Calcualate B based on _values 
    }

    C calculateC(unsigned i) const
    {
        //Calcualate A based on _values 
    }

    std::vector<unsigned>           _values;
};
```

**Version 2** - Functions `calculateA(),calculateB() and calculateC()` are not dependent on `calculateAll()`

```
class Box
{
    void calculateAll()
    {
        calculateA();
        calculateB();
        calculateC();
    }

    A calculateA() const
    {
        for(const auto& value: _values)
        {
            //Calcualate A based on _values 
        }
    }

    B calculateB() const
    {
        for(const auto& value: _values)
        {
            //Calcualate B based on _values 
        }
    }

    C calculateC() const
    {
        for(const auto& value: _values)
        {
            //Calcualate C based on _values 
        }
    }


    std::vector<unsigned>           _values;
};
```

Which version is more cleaner? Which version is better performance wise? Is there a better implementation that these?

Comment: Without knowing what each `calculate` does, I am not sure it is possible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This largely depends on your use case. If there are situations that call for only calculating based off of certain values or subsets of values, then the second version should be preferred, but if you are always going be calculating all values, then the first should be preferred.